# Displaying DATA from SQL DB

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider the example below,

3 Tables in a Data base 'First Name, Last Name, and Age'
I have all the First Names and Last Names, and I need to write a query to display the AGE associated with the data I provided.

For example:

```
First_Name | Last_Name | Age
-----------------------------
Mark       | Thomas    | 23
Vince      | Erickson  | 29
Peter      | Charlton  | 36
```

I need a query that I can provide the First and Last name, and it displays the result of the provided data, including their age.

Something like,

```
SELECT Age 
FROM Users_DB 
WHERE First_Name = (Mark, Vince, Peter) 
AND Last_Name = (Thomas, Eickson, Charlton)
```

Because I have a list of 200 users (First Name, and Last Name), and I need to grab their age from the Database which contains over 5000 users. I only need to display the age of those 200 users.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you are going to use relational databases, you need to start by learning the difference between a "database", a "table", and a "column".  You seem to have one table with three columns in one database.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax of your query is:

```
SELECT Age 
FROM Users_DB 
WHERE First_Name IN ('Mark', 'Vince', 'Peter') 
    AND Last_Name IN ('Thomas', 'Erickson', 'Charlton');
```

But I don't believe it's what you really want, because it will also select people who are named Mark Thomas or Mark Erickson or Mark Charlton.

So, I think what you want to do here is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Users_DB 
WHERE (First_Name = 'Mark' AND Last_Name = 'Thomas') 
    OR (First_Name = 'Vince' AND Last_Name = 'Erickson') 
    OR (First_Name = 'Peter' AND Last_Name = 'Charlton');
```

Comment: The 2nd syntax is fairly close to what I want. Is there a way to make the method any easier that (First_Name = "" AND Last_Name = ""), because I have over 200 record. Also, if I was to run this, would I get results shown similar to how it is in the DB example I provided above? as in, the age will be associated with the first name and last name I provided?

Comment: Well, if you just want to see every age of every person in your DB table, you don't even need to user a WHERE statement. SELECT * FROM Users_DB; should do the trick.
If you want to get only specific people, you'll have to use a WHERE statement with the (First_Name = '' AND Last_Name = '') for every person, unfortunately.
Finally, of course the result will show as they are recorded in the DB, the age will be associated to the correct person, that's what databases are all about :)

Comment: I updated my original message, to explain my current situation. It should maybe help you understand what I'm looking for. Thanks in advance

Comment: Oh, ok, are the 200 users you need to display specific? Or do you want to display 200 users no matter who they are? In the first case you would have to use LIMIT 200.

Comment: The 1st case is the one I'm after, but .. the problem is those 200 users are not in order, sadly. So I can't use LIMIT 200, right? Else it will start from 1st entry, count 200, and then stop.

Comment: So, what you want is display 200 users with their age, and these users  must be randomly picked?